# Run task in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, scheduled-tasks

I am writing a small app in VB and I would like to know how I would set it up so that when a user pressed a button, a sechduled task is ran. Keep in mind that this task is already created, I just need it to run.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If the task is already scheduled, wouldn't it automatically run as scheduled?

Comment: If the task is already scheduled in task manager, shouldn't task manager run the task, per your schedule? Or are you trying to run the task per your schedule and also run it manually when you click a button?

Comment: I hope you are looking for starting a process. Scheduling a process doesn't need a button to start it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the System.Diagnostics.Process class. You can create a process and run it with Process.Start() method.

**EDIT:**
Following code sample starts the helloworld.exe. This is just to give an idea about the Process class. You can find this example in [Process.Start Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyProcessSample
{
    class MyProcess
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Process myProcess = new Process();

            try
            {
                myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                // You can start any process, HelloWorld is a do-nothing example.
                myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\HelloWorld.exe";
                myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                myProcess.Start();
                // This code assumes the process you are starting will terminate itself. 
                // Given that is is started without a window so you cannot terminate it 
                // on the desktop, it must terminate itself or you can do it programmatically
                // from this application using the Kill method.
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please refer to the answer edited with an example. You can find more detail in the hyperlink provided.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the recently added System.Threading.Tasks library?

Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.aspx